# some other reason vs some reason, is the meaning the same?

Tags: meaning, determiners

I would like to know whether the following sentences convey the very same meaning ("strong some"):

> There must be some reason/way.
>    There must be some other reason/way.

I mean, the first one is an obvious case of the "strong some" use. But does it also apply for the other one?

Comment: *There must be some reason* implies that even though you don't know what that reason is, you believe it must exist. *There must be some **other** reason* implies that you ***already know at least one reason*** (which you might or might not have considered and rejected), but you believe there must be a ***different*** reason (*in addition to* the one / ones you already know - or *instead of,* if you've already rejected that / those).

Comment: ...the way you'd convey "strong some" (by which I assume you mean emphatically rejecting the possibility that something "just happened", for no particular reason) would normally be by simply enunciating the word ***some*** with heavy stress - or a "stand-out" font such as italics or boldface in the written form).

Comment: @FumbleFingers By "strong some" I mean "some" used with singular countable nouns, e.g. Some idiot crashed my car. Basically I am not sure whether "some" in both sentences has the same meaning, as it is used with singular nouns.

Comment: Echoing you car example, *I suppose there's some reason you chose that example.* I'd say that ***some*** there is actually extremely "weak" (it could just as easily be plain ***a** reason*, and wouldn't be likely to carry heavy stress). And in the most likely context that comes to mind, the implication would be that the speaker doesn't actually know or care exactly ***which*** idiot or reason he's referring to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes I was thought that "strong" some is used when you want to express that you do not know / do not care, and so the emphasis is put on this word.

Comment: Yeah, well. It's nothing to do with either of us being "right" (or wrong) about what a "strong some" might mean, since it's not an established collocation. Also I've belatedly realised that it can be perfectly natural to say *I'm sure there's **some** reason why he said that* with heavy stress as indicated, in a context where the speaker really doesn't care a bit what that reason might be (and in fact wishes to imply that ***whatever*** that reason is, he would reject it anyway if he could be bothered to find out what it was).